# Show button based on access rights

Tags: xml, button, odoo, usergroups, access-rights

The default of the button is invisible.

Access Right Scenario: 
User: The button will show if create_uid is not equal to the partner_id
Manager: This button will always display.

What I did was:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_custom_approve']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">attrs="{'visible':[('groups_ids','=','group_user'),('groups_ids','=','group_manager')]}"</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Any idea on how to achieve it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [create_uid](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.create_uid) stores who created the record, [Many2one](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2one) to a `res.users`. You have to provide only the `attrs` value (do not include `attrs`)

Unfortunately, you can't use `partner_id` in `attrs` domain, but you can hide the button based on a computed boolean field that implement the above logic.

For example, if we define a boolean field like following:

```py
button_state = fields.Boolean(compute="_compute_button_state")

@api.depends('create_uid', 'partner_id')
def _compute_button_state(self):
    for record in self:
        record.button_state = (record.partner_id != record.create_uid and self.env.user.has_group("group_user")) or self.env.user.has_group("group_manager")
```

To hide the button based on that field, we use the following syntax:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_custom_approve']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('button_state', '=', False)]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

In the example above, `partner_id` is supposed to be a `Many2one` to a `res.users`